# Why do I get invalid conversion from int** to const int**?

Tags: c++

As I've already learned about pointers in C++, I can initialize a pointer to`const` with a non-const object as the fact that this pointer is just used to read only e.g:

```
 int x{10};
 const int* p{ &x }; // ok. p can change addr but not the value inside it.
```

But the contrary is not allowed: We cannot initialize a pointer to non-const with a const object because if allowed this transgresses the rule of constness e.g:

```
const double Pi{ 3.14};
double* pPi{ &Pi }; // not allowed.
```

Until now it is clear for me. but when it comes to Multiple-level of indirection mixed with constness,  things get complicated for me. e.g:

```
int x{ 57 };
int* p{ &x };
const int** pp{ &p }; // why this not allowed?
```

As you can see above, I get compile-time error:

> invalid conversion from ' int**' to 'const int**'

However if I make it this way:

```
int x{ 57 };
int* p{ &x };
const int* const* pp{ &p }; // ok
```

Or this also works:

```
int x{ 57 };
const int* p{ &x };
const int** pp{ &p }; // ok
```

Please help me to understand why allowed/not allowed. I am not intending  to mess up with pointers but just to know how things can/cannot work.

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion

Comment: @M.M Thank you for the link.